# kdb q - efficiently count tables in flatfiles

Tags: kdb

I have a lot of tables stored in flat files (in a directory called `basepath`) and I want to check their number of rows. The best I can so right now is:

```
c:([] filename:system "ls ",basepath; 
      tablesize:count each get each hsym `$basepath,/:system "ls ",basepath)
```

which loads each table entirely into memory and then performs the count (that's quite slow). Is saving as splayed tables the only way to make this faster (because I would only load 1 column and count that) or is there a trick in q that I can use?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From experimenting with the binary files, it seems that the table count is saved as part of the binary file when you save down a flat file, taking up 4 bytes after the initial object type and column headings which will vary from table to table.

```
`:test set ([]a:1 2 3;b:4 5 6;c:7 8 9;aa:10 11 12;bb:13 14 15)
q)read1 `:test
0xff016200630b000500000061006200630061610062620000000500000009000300000
  0             7       11                                      31          

bytes             | example                  | meaning
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 - 5             | 0xff016200630b0          | object is a flat table
7 - 11            | 0x05000000               | number of columns (5)
12- 22            | 0x6100620063006161006262 | one byte for the ascii values of column "a" and "b" in hex followed by the one byte separator
23 - 30           | 0x0000050000000900       | 8 bytes that can be skipped
31 - 34           | 0x0300000                | 4 bytes for row count of first column (3)
```

This should help you understand the function that Fiona posted.

The binary is saved down little-endian meaning the most-significant byte is the right-hand most digit - doing this in decimal for the number 100 would give 001, with the 100's (most significant) on the right and then 10s and finally 1s on the left. In the binary file, each group of 2 digits is a byte.

You can use `1:` to read in the contents of a binary file, with additional arguments in the list specifying the offset - where to start reading from, and how many bytes to read. In our case we want to start at byte 31 and read in 4 bytes, specifying the output should be an integer and to cut the input into separate 4 byte chunks.

```
q)first first (enlist "i";enlist 4)1:(`:test;31;4)
3i
```

Converting the little-endian bytes into a long gives us the row count. Since this only has to read in 4 bytes instead of the whole file it is a lot quicker.

For a table with 10000 rows and 2 columns there is not much difference:

```
q)\t 0x0 sv reverse first (enlist "x";enlist 1)1:(`:test10000;31;4)
0
q)\t count get `:test10000
0
```

For a table with 100m rows and 2 columns:

```
q)\t 0x0 sv reverse first (enlist "x";enlist 1)1:(`:test10m;31;4)
0
q)\t count get `:test10m
2023
```

If you have a splayed table instead you can read in the number of elements in one of the columns from bytes 9-13 like so, assuming the column is a simple list:

```
q)first first (enlist "i";enlist 4)1:(`:a;8;4)
3i
```

You can read more about reading in from binary files here https://code.kx.com/q/ref/filenumbers/#1-binary-files

Comment: Better version of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52660654/3904820)

Answer (score 4):

If you have basepath defined as a string of the path to directory where all your flat tables are stored then you can create a dictionary of the row counts as follows:

```
q)cnt:{count get hsym x}
q)filename:key hsym `$basepath
q)filename!cnt each filename
t| 2
g| 3
```

This is where I have flat tables t and g saved in my basepath directory. This stops you from having to use `system` commands which are often less effiecient.
The function `cnt` takes the path of each flat table (as a symbol) and returns the number of rows without saving them into memory.

The best solution if you have control of the process of saving such files down is to add an extra step of saving the meta information of the row count somewhere seperate at the same time of saving the raw data. This would allow you to quickly access the table size from this file instead of reading the full tbale in each time.

However, note that to avoid pulling them into memory at all you would have to instead use `read1` and look at the headers on the binary data. As you said it would be better to save as a splayed table and read in one column.

UPDATE: I would not recommend doing this and strongly suggest doing the above but for curiosity after looking into using `read1` here's an example what what a hacky solution might look like:

```
f:{
  b:read1(y;0;x);
  if[not 0x62630b~b[2 4 5];'`$"not a table"];
  cc:first first((),"i";(),4)1:b 7+til 4;
  if[null ce:first where cc=sums 0x0=11 _ b;:.z.s[x*2;y]];
  c:`$"\000" vs "c"$b[11+til ce];
  n:first first((),"i";(),4)1:b[(20+ce)+til 4];
  :`columns`rows!(c;n);
  }[2000]
```

The q binary file format isn’t documented anywhere, the only way to figure it out is to save different things and see how the bytes change. It’s also subject to changes between versions - the above is written for 3.5 and is probably valid for 3.0-3.5 only, not the latest 3.6 release or anything 2.X.

The given code works in the following way:

1. reads a chunk from the front of the file
2. validates that it looks like a flat unkeyed table (flip[98] of a dict[99] with symbol[11] keys)
3. reads the count of symbols in the list of columns as a little endian 4 byte int
4. scans through the null terminated strings for that many zero bytes
5. if the columns are so numerous or verbose that we don’t have them
   all in this chunk it will double the size of the chunk and try again
6. turn the strings into symbols
7. using the offset we get from the end of the column list, skip a bit
   more of the header for the mixed list of columns
8. then read the count from the header of the first column

Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 3):

You can make what you currently have more efficient by using the following

> counttables:{count each get each hsym `$basepath}

This will improve the speed of the count by not including the extra read in of the data as well as the join which you are currently doing. You are correct though that if the tables where saved splayed you would only have to read in the one column making it much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are stored uncompressed there's probably something quite hacky you could do with a read1 on the headers within the file until you find the first column header.

But v hacky :-(

Are you responsible for saving these down? Can you keep a running state as you do?